# Django 1.9: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Not specified' "

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm currently learning Python. I was trying to add a new field(product_group) as a Foreign Key to basic Django User class. But when I'm trying to "python manage.py migrate" I get this error message:

```
> C:\Users\Дима\PycharmProjects\SupportYourApp2>python manage.py migrate
> Operations to perform:   Apply all migrations: Authentication_System,
> contenttypes, admin, auth, sessions Running migrations:   Rendering
> model states... DONE   Applying
> Authentication_System.0003_customuser_product_group...Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
>     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
> line 350, in execute_f rom_command_line
>     utility.execute()   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
> line 342, in execute
>     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
> line 348, in run_from_argv
> 
>     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
> line 399, in execute
>     output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py",
> line 200, in h andle
>     executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
> "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
> line 92, in migrate
>     self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
> "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
> line 121, in _migrate_al l_forwards
>     state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
> "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
> line 198, in apply_migra tion
>     state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py",
> line 123, in apply
>     operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)   File
> "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py",
> line 62, in dat abase_forwards
>     field,   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py",
> line 221, in add_fie ld
>     self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py",
> line 103, in _remake
> _table
>     self.effective_default(field)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py",
> line 210, in effective_ default
>     default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py",
> line 910, in get_db_pr ep_save
>     return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)   File
> "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py",
> line 728, in get_db_p rep_save
>     prepared=False)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py",
> line 968, in get_db_p rep_value
>     value = self.get_prep_value(value)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py",
> line 976, in get_prep
> _value
>     return int(value) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Not specified'
> 
> C:\Users\Дима\PycharmProjects\SupportYourApp2>python manage.py migrate
> Operations to perform:   Apply all migrations: contenttypes, admin,
> Authentication_System, auth, sessions Running migrations:   Rendering
> model states... DONE   Applying
> Authentication_System.0003_customuser_product_group...Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
>     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
> line 350, in execute_f rom_command_line
>     utility.execute()   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
> line 342, in execute
>     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
> line 348, in run_from_argv
> 
>     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
> line 399, in execute
>     output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py",
> line 200, in h andle
>     executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
> "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
> line 92, in migrate
>     self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
> "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
> line 121, in _migrate_al l_forwards
>     state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
> "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
> line 198, in apply_migra tion
>     state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py",
> line 123, in apply
>     operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)   File
> "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py",
> line 62, in dat abase_forwards
>     field,   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py",
> line 221, in add_fie ld
>     self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py",
> line 103, in _remake
> _table
>     self.effective_default(field)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py",
> line 210, in effective_ default
>     default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py",
> line 910, in get_db_pr ep_save
>     return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)   File
> "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py",
> line 728, in get_db_p rep_save
>     prepared=False)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py",
> line 968, in get_db_p rep_value
>     value = self.get_prep_value(value)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py",
> line 976, in get_prep
> _value
>     return int(value) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Not specified'
> 
> C:\Users\Дима\PycharmProjects\SupportYourApp2>python manage.py
> makemigrations Migrations for 'Authentication_System':  
> 0017_auto_20160427_1859.py:
>     - Alter field product_group on customuser
> 
> C:\Users\Дима\PycharmProjects\SupportYourApp2>python manage.py migrate
> Operations to perform:   Apply all migrations: auth, admin,
> Authentication_System, contenttypes, sessions Running migrations:  
> Rendering model states... DONE   Applying
> Authentication_System.0003_customuser_product_group...Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
>     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
> line 350, in execute_f rom_command_line
>     utility.execute()   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
> line 342, in execute
>     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
> line 348, in run_from_argv
> 
>     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
> line 399, in execute
>     output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py",
> line 200, in h andle
>     executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
> "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
> line 92, in migrate
>     self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
> "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
> line 121, in _migrate_al l_forwards
>     state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
> "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
> line 198, in apply_migra tion
>     state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py",
> line 123, in apply
>     operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)   File
> "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py",
> line 62, in dat abase_forwards
>     field,   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py",
> line 221, in add_fie ld
>     self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py",
> line 103, in _remake
> _table
>     self.effective_default(field)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py",
> line 210, in effective_ default
>     default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py",
> line 910, in get_db_pr ep_save
>     return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)   File
> "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py",
> line 728, in get_db_p rep_save
>     prepared=False)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py",
> line 968, in get_db_p rep_value
>     value = self.get_prep_value(value)   File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py",
> line 976, in get_prep
> _value
>     return int(value) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Not specified'
```

Here is my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.utils.http import urlquote
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core import validators

# Create your models here.
class ProductsGroup(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Group of products'

    groupName = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return format(self.groupName)

######################################### USER MODEL #########################################
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username, email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user( email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=False, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=30,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(
                r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                _('Enter a valid username. This value may contain only '
                  'letters, numbers ' 'and @/./+/-/_ characters.')
            ),
        ],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    product_group = models.ForeignKey(ProductsGroup, default=2)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username',]


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/users/%s/' % urlquote(self.email)

    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.second_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def emai_user(self, subject, message, from_email = None):
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])
```

I would greatly appriciate any advice.

Comment: try this convert the default value into literals 
`product_group = models.ForeignKey(ProductsGroup, default='2')`

or you have to pass the object by first getting it using the id from the ProductsGroup table and set the default vale to object.

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib Thank you, but converting the default value into literals was not the solution. 
"you have to pass the object by first getting it using the id from the ProductsGroup table and set the default vale to object." - I'm not quite sure how to do that. Maybe you can give me some pseudocode sample?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give you any hint in your case. Maybe it is because you don't have any entries in your `Productsgroup` model. But as a default your giving `2` (this is an id of an entry I guess in a database) like this `default=2`. This can cause problems if you don't have any entries yet.

But, actually, you shouldn't extend a `User` model like that. As it is mentioned here:

> Think carefully before handling information not directly related to authentication in your custom User Model.
>
> It may be better to store app-specific user information in a model
>   that has a relation with the User model.

`ProductGroup` does not seem to have any relations to authentication system, so, if you want to add some additional information to your users, then you can extend django's built-in user model simply by creating another model and relating it with `oneToOneField` to the built-in user model. 
You can get whole explanation for that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

Comment: Thank you. 'oneToOneField' relation is a really good solution and I already have done it before(it was working fine). In this code sample, I was trying to understand how to extend basic Django User model using this exact method.
'ProductGroup' is related to 'User' as 'oneToManyField' (One product group can have many users and one user can have only one group).

Comment: I was trying to add entries to DB. I was trying 'ForeignKey(ProductsGroup)' and 'ForeignKey(ProductsGroup, blank=True)' - the result was the same as in this message.
So if you have any other advice please let me know.

Comment: What about `django`s built-in group functionality?

Comment: You can create a group and add users to that group. Or again you can create another model something like `profile` or even `group` then relate it with `User` model and use it. Anyway as far as I know it does not seem to be the best method of extending `User` like this.

Comment: Also it would be very helpful if you could give the contents of your migrations file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was **to create a new project**.
As they say in [Django 1.9 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/):

> Due to limitations of Django’s dynamic dependency feature for
>   swappable models, you must ensure that the model referenced by
>   AUTH_USER_MODEL is **created in the first migration** of its app (usually
>   called 0001_initial); otherwise, you will have dependency issues.

I've also changed `product_group = models.ForeignKey(ProductsGroup, blank=True, null=True)` in `models.py` in order to solve this issue while creating superuser:

`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: Authentication_System_customuser.product_group_id`

For now everything is working.